# Duplicate delete query in binary log of MySql Master

Tags: mysql, replication

We are facing strange problem, while replication data from master to slave. Same data is being deleted twice in log(How ever only one row is deleted and one time),due to which we are getting error while replication.

```
# at 28651234
#150423 12:21:03 server id 5170  end_log_pos 28651303 CRC32 0x0b496431  Delete_rows: table id 73 flags: STMT_END_F
### DELETE FROM `oauth`.`AccessToken_scopes`
### WHERE
###   @1=1040103520
###   @2='wallet'
### DELETE FROM `oauth`.`AccessToken_scopes`
### WHERE
###   @1=1040103520
###   @2='wallet'
```

To avoid this,we currently have added below parameter in `my.cnf` file.

```
slave-skip-errors
```

Comment: You might get better (and quicker) answers at the sister site dba.stackexchange.com. It's specifically for database administration questions.